# Problem to remove distortion (after camera-calibration) from image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

The [image](https://ibb.co/b1hqDsZ) is a single frame of a 90-minute video.

If one draws a line from the top left corner (see, [left-distorted](https://ibb.co/FnT90WP)) to the right (see, [right-distorted](https://ibb.co/6sJc9tz)), the distortion is visible by looking at the top-line (see, [middle-distorted](https://ibb.co/7kVdW5W)).

The white line between the points to the left and the right should be straight but has a slight U-shape compared to the straight line in red.

Performing a camera calibration with open-cv ([reference](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html)) using a sample of entire frames from calibration videos (for some examples see, [indoor](https://ibb.co/JvgkYw5), [outdoor-1](http://ibb.co/zmVbN88), and [outdoor-2](https://ibb.co/KDPLMmP)) results in this [undistorted](https://ibb.co/X7ZHK0b) image.

Here, the line from the top left corner (see, [left-undistorted](https://ibb.co/1zxKrkN)) to the right (see, [right-undistorted](https://ibb.co/KFfk9dD)) overcorrects the distortion as the difference between the red-line and the white has become an inverse U shape (see, [middle-undistorted](https://ibb.co/tmsdqQ4)).

I took the recording with an iPhone 11, and I am using python 3.8.8 and open-cv 4.5.3.

I followed the advice I could find at StackOverflow (and through the most popular search results), but using any checkerboard (variation of size, camera angle, distance, and setting) does not correct distortion correction. I fail to understand why.

**UPDATE:**

Based on below conversation the calibration footage needs to

- have a focus, similar to the reference scenario (in my case, objects are far away),
- the board should cover a minimum of say 20% of the image.

Here the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CUVMATE8xLs13yod01BC5myqjbLVcCoD/view?usp=sharing) that I used (focus is fixed on objects being far away) to extract a sample of 50 frames to calculate the camera calibration:

```
SQUARE_SIZE = 0.012
CHECKERBOARD_WIDTH = 22
CHECKERBOARD_HEIGHT = 15

objpoints = []
imgpoints = []

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
val = cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK + cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE
SAMPLE_SIZE = 50

objp = np.zeros((CHECKERBOARD_HEIGHT * CHECKERBOARD_WIDTH, 3), np.float32)
objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:CHECKERBOARD_WIDTH, 0:CHECKERBOARD_HEIGHT.T.reshape(-1, 2)
objp = objp * SQUARE_SIZE

# for loop going over the sample of images
img = cv2.imread('path to image')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (CHECKERBOARD_WIDTH[i], CHECKERBOARD_HEIGHT[i]), val)
if ret == True:
    objpoints.append(objp)
    # refining pixel coordinates for given 2d points.
    corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
    imgpoints.append(corners2)

# Calculate camera calibration
img = cv2.imread('path to reference image')
h,w = img.shape[:2]
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints,
                                                   imgpoints,
                                                   (w,h),
                                                   None,
                                                   None)                                          

newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w,h), 1, (w,h))

# Undistort
mapx,mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx, (w,h), 5)
dst = cv2.remap(img,mapx,mapy,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
cv2.imwrite('path to output image', dst)
```

The [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pS_j_gc1vZvys-0hO2clWKirM4Ou2Oey/view?usp=sharing) is unfortunately not correct as shown by the deviation of the red and white line at the top of the pitch.

Comment: you don't need to stand on the field with a billboard. you do however need to get calibration points (chessboard corners) in the corners of the view. that's where distortion is most severe, and where data for calibration is most needed. I'd also recommend that the calibration pattern span a good portion of the image, as in the indoor picture. 1-5% as in the outdoor pics, is just not enough.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. Judging by the reference image (first one), the distortion is most severe at the top and at the sides where the vertical lines of the fence bend inwards. I tried pictures like the indoor one (several that span the entire image and align differently with different angles to the camera - like the one I shared), but I did not get the desired result. As I could not remove the distortion, I tried to replicate the original  (outdoor) setting. I walk around the entire image, and the sum of images covers the whole scene (especially the top part). What do you mean by 1-5%?

Comment: 1-5% by area, i.e. very small. -- make sure the camera's focus is fixed. varying focus 
(real autofocus) definitely changes "the lens". focus at infinity is a good idea... which means calibration "in the lab" will require some distance between the camera and the board. I'm guessing a few meters. an A4 or A3 printed sheet on cardboard ought to be just fine.

Comment: Ok, that's good advice. So the procedure is this (a) focus on something that is as far away as the reference footage (or ensure that the focal length is infinite) and lock the camera to keep that focus (b) make a picture of the chessboard that covers (almost) the entire picture. An issue with (b) is that the chessboard will be blurry as there is a big difference in focal length. Should I take several images from a greater distance (as you say, a few meters) but align the chessboard in different screen areas and use this for calibration?

Comment: yes. I would say the board should appear at least half as wide as the field of view (image size) for good data. if it gets much smaller, say not even 10-20% as wide... it's like putting a straightedge to a globe to measure its curvature (lens distortion). a straightedge the size of your fingernail will proclaim that the earth is flat (no lens distortion).

Comment: One more question: the angle of the checkerboard to the camera (being on something flat, of course) and its rotation can be anything not (given that the alignment of the checkerboard should still be maintained, of course)?

Comment: yes, but for some reason I always angle it rather than show it frontally. for ARUCO markers, frontal view gives larger error in angles. it's like calculating arccos of 0.999something.

Comment: Angle in terms of rotating the picture or angle between the camera to the picture (which would produce vanishing points)? Here the video I just took: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TB_4lxmNhkRpHpeC4x8GJ-dV0zozec1D/view?usp=sharing (for some reason the corners can't be detected for the first frames when the board is covering the majority of the image - but that's a different issue). Would you advise to use ARUCO? I read that checkerboard is enough and its easier :)

Comment: yeah that's gonna need different focus or be further away.

Comment: Based on our previous conversation, the requirements for good data are: (a) the focus needs to be similar to the reference scenario (in my case, objects are far away), and (b) the chessboard should cover a minimum of say 20% of the image. My problem is that the chessboard will be blurry when (a) is focusing on objects being far away (my case), and minimum coverage of the board, i.e., (b), needs to be maintained. I struggle to find a robust way to record a video that satisfies (a,b) and properly undistorts the reference picture. I updated the original post to show the video/code/output.